# When using Ember CLI http-mock is it possible to stop express updating?

Tags: express, ember.js, ember-cli

I have been using http-mock with Ember CLI. Today I generated a new http-mock with

```
ember generate http-mock myobject
```

I found afterwards that my package.json file had been updated from express 4.12.4 to 4.13.0

```
 - "express": "^4.12.4",

 + "express": "^4.13.0",
```

Our Ember CLI version has remained constant, it just so happens express released a new version (https://github.com/strongloop/express/releases/tag/4.13.0) between the first time we used http-mock and today.

We would rather manage dependency changes by themselves as and when we want to, but still be able to create new http-mock's when we want them. Can I run the command slightly differently to prevent express upgrading it's version?

Comment: The culprit is the `afterInstall` hook in the [blueprint](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/blueprints/http-mock/index.js#L31), other than forking and modifying that area I don't think you ll be able to prevent `http-mock` from updating express to whatever version they have atm.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've opened an issue on github to see whether this is a bug, possible enhancement or intended https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was identified as undesired behavior in Ember CLI 1.13.1 and has been fixed as an enhancement under this pull request https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/4452.

To stop http-mock from updating express etc the answer is to upgrade to the next version of Ember CLI after 1.13.1, when it is released.